# Wald General Relativity, Chap 7.1

Tags: general-relativity

On page 166 of Wald's General Relativity book, he claims that the equation (7.1.20),
$$ 0 = R^t{}_t + R^\phi{}_\phi = (\nabla_a t) R^a{}_b \xi^b + (\nabla_a \phi) R^a{}_b \psi^b, $$
yields (7.1.21),
$$ D^a D_a \rho = 0. $$
He is working in an axisymmetric spacetime, and $D_a$ is the covariant derivative in the $\rho{-}z$-plane. Also, $\xi^a = (\partial/\partial t)^a$ and $\psi^a = (\partial/\partial\phi)^a$. I don't see how the two are related. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you might need to flesh this out for those of us without Wald sitting in front of us...

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Echoing @DJBunk, it would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open a book or link to understand the question.

Comment: Well, I think you need to just write it out. (7.1.19) is the metric in ($t,\phi,\rho,z$) basis, and V,X and W are defined on a page before. So you need to calculate (you can always use Mathematica and GRTensor for checking your result) the first equation, and then the second equation, and they should be the same.

Comment: Oh gosh! I really wasn't expecting an answer. Many, many thanks!